# Extend ng-if or implement similar directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to include or exclude content based on a boolean value.
The boolean value comes from a service that provides feature toggles.  I don't want to inject the directive in a lot of places or use `$root` in a condition for `ng-if`.

So I would like to create an AngularJS attribute directive that is similar to `ng-if` but has the service injected and includes/excludes the content based on the boolean value, instead of getting a condition expression from the attribute value in the template.

Is it possible to somehow extend the existing `ng-if` directive?  If not, what would be the easiest/best way to implement similar behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple directive embedding a service which when it executes the linking function will decide whether or not to display the DOM element based on the value returned from the service. The directive relies on the currentUser service to return the value which would normally be part of the ng-if expression. It evaluates this in the linking function so the assumption is that this value is static and does not need to be re-evaluated. In fact, it cannot be re-evaluated as we totally remove the element from the DOM.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button is-admin>ADMIN BUTTON</button>
    <button>REGULAR BUTTON</button>
    <script>
      
      var app=angular.module("app",[]);
      
      app.service("currentUser",function(){
        
        return {
          isAuthorized : function(){return false;}
        }
        
      });
      
      app.directive("isAdmin",["currentUser", function(currentUser){
        
        var linkFx = function(scope,elem,attrs){
          debugger;
          if(!currentUser.isAuthorized()){
            elem[0].remove();
          }
        }
        
        return {
          link: linkFx,
          restrict: "A"
        }
        
      }]);
      
      angular.bootstrap(document,[app.name]);
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It does show or hide the content like `ng-show` or `ng-hide`... any way it can work like `ng-if` instead?

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to do what I need.  I will leave the question open a bit longer in order to evaluate possible alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach perhaps, and that is have an object in any parent controller, and use that object to do whatever.

So if your first controller is `MainCtrl` you can:

```
$scope.serviceDataWrapper = function() {
    return MyService.getValue();
}
```

and use the regular `ng-if` anywhere, even if it involves different controllers:

```
<div ng-if="serviceDataWrapper()"></div>
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to AngularJS, but I've read in several places that I should not use `$scope` and that it will be removed in Angular 2.

Comment: Well I think that moving to Angular 2 will involve a full re-factor anyway, so this shouldn't hold you back...

Comment: I'm already starting to implement directives as components (using AngularJS 1.5), I'd like to keep the migration path as painless as possible.